# Restore-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem cmdlet to Restore As Files

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-backup-vault

I have a requirement to (as part of an automation) grab the latest full backup from a Recovery Services vault and "Restore as Files" it (see screenshot below) before moving it to a different subscription for ... restoration?

I want to automate this action:

[image]

The `Restore-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem` seems to fit the bill, but can't figure out how to configure it to restore the files, rather than the database. [Example 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.recoveryservices/restore-azrecoveryservicesbackupitem?view=azps-9.0.1#example-7-restore-a-sql-db-within-an-azure-vm-to-another-target-vm-for-a-distinct-full-recovery-point) is almost there, but not quite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overview of the procedure is as follows:

1. Get the vault via `Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault`
2. Get the backup item via `Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem`
3. Get the recovery point via `Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupRecoveryPoint`
4. Get the container to restore it to via `Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer`
5. Build a configuration for the restore job via `Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupWorkloadRecoveryConfig`, with the kicker here specifying the `-RestoreAsFiles` and `-FilePath` parameters.
6. Execute the restore via `Restore-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem`

Full script:

```
$vaultName = ""
$backupItemName = ""
$sourceServerName = ""
$restorePath = ""

$vault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -Name $vaultName
$backupItem = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -BackupManagementType AzureWorkload -WorkloadType MSSQL -VaultId $vault.ID -Name $backupItemName -ProtectionStatus Healthy | where-object {$_.ServerName -eq $sourceServerName }
$latestFullRP = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupRecoveryPoint -Item $BackupItem -StartDate ((Get-Date).AddDays(-3)).ToUniversalTime() -EndDate (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -VaultId $vault.ID | Sort-Object -Descending -Property RecoveryPointTime | Select-Object -First 1
$container = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureVMAppContainer -VaultId $Vault.Id | Where-Object {$_.ServerName -eq $sourceServerName -and $_.HealthStatus -eq 'Healthy'}
$restoreConfig = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupWorkloadRecoveryConfig -RecoveryPoint $latestFullRP -TargetItem $Target -TargetContainer $Container -RestoreAsFiles -VaultId $vault.ID -FilePath $restorePath

Restore-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -WLRecoveryConfig $restoreConfig -ResolveConflict Overwrite -VaultId $vault.ID
```

Comment: Bumped into a couple issues using the script sample, some flags were wrong, some attributes were named differently, but in general this was very helpful thanks. I made some small changes to the sample script you provided.

Comment: In case interested, credit for my verbose script goes mainly to 
https://github.com/treytro/Samples/blob/master/RestoreSQLFromAzureRecoveryVault.ps1

The changes that I've made can be seen in my own repo here:
https://github.com/kaburkett/devops-scripts/blob/master/RestoreSQLfromARV.ps1

I took elements from your answer and incorporated them with the nice Azure Automation script provided by Trey